# ASP.NET based Report Designer for Reporting Services 2008 Report creation

Tags: ssrs-2008

Does anyone has any information on a ASP.NET based alternative to Report Builder? Basically we would like to have the report designer integrated into our ASP.NET based application for end to end seamless experience.

Today we are able to display the our put of Reporting Services Reports in our application, however for designing the report users still have to go outside of the application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However what I am really looking for is ASP.NET based alternative of Report Builder tool which is a thick client application specially for Business Users where they can create well formatted financial reports. I remembered sometime back one company doing that but not able to recall.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make your own, don't forget than rdl and rdlc files are just XML files !

If you look at the rdlc file structure you'll see it's quite easy to generate it.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking into this myself... I agree with the post from ykatchou, it is all based on XML, if any ad hoc reporting viewers are not, they are basically in a big mess (Telerik). The structure itself may not be too difficult to generate as one could parse the DOM with JQuery. Post the results to server side, ensure the xml document conforms to a DTD once saving and that way you know valid XHTML => xml is produced. Strip out all content you do not need, you can:

1. XML + XSLT
2. Parse the XML file using server side code and take what you need

The resulting xml file will still need to be passed into a rendering engine, i.e. one that can take the xml file with the correct styling in place and throw out the PDF... It does take a while but conceptually I know it is all possible as I am drilling deeper into this. XSL:FO is very interesting too, I mean get the XML + XSLT to return an xsl:fo file and you should be flying, no?